# Xampp, Access forbidden for non index files

Tags: php, xampp

I've been using xampp for a long time and it's always worked fine.  I have a project I am currently working on and it was working fine just a couple of days ago. Now I am getting 403 Access forbidden page for any file that is not named index.php.  Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening.

I'm on Windows XP and have Xampp Version 1.6.4 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be an issue with the .htaccess file (or httpd.conf file).

Something to keep in mind:

The way that Apache handles .htaccess rules is "cascading" meaning that it will check every .htaccess file along the path of the file you are trying to access, so if you have some rule forbidding users from viewing any non-index files at any point, it will affect all deeper directories.

Having said that, if you know the issue isn't with the `httpd.conf` file, check to see if the root of the publishing path has a `.htaccess` file. Change it to `.htaccessold` and see if you can access any files in the htdocs directory other than index.

Two questions:

1. Do you get this for all files, or just php files? can you see image files, etc?
2. What about index.html? If you change your `index.php` to `tempindex.php` and create a new blah file called `index.html` can you see that?

Good luck. Keep me posted.

Comment: Oh, and I just read your comment to zombat. You said that you don't have an htaccess file, which actually makes my point about them more relevant (but not necessarily to your problem). If you have ANY htaccess files along the path, it will affect that directory. So double check (a simple find should do it) that you didn't overlook one much higher in the path.

Comment: Oh, and the config file is actually going to be called "httpd.conf" which I updated in my answer. If you go to your xampp directory, then `apache > conf` you'll find it there. Look for the term access or allow.  Also, check that same directory for any other conf files that may suggest access rights.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. Can you leave a comment on the specifics of the solution so I can brag to my friends?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can see why Apache is returning this error message is to look at the error log.

We can guess at possible causes, but Apache will be able to tell you if you take the time to look.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you changed some `mod_rewrite` rules or your site's apache configuration.  Did you add or change anything in an `.htaccess` file?

You're probably going to have to give more details in order to figure this out.

Comment: Hi zombat,

I didn't touch the mod_rewrite and I don't have an .htaccess file.

Comment: How about providing more details about your set up then?  Edit your question to add them.